# libgdx - adding multiple actors in one table cell with scene2d

Tags: android, libgdx, scene2d

I would like to add multiple actors to one table cell with scene2d.

My table has 3 cells on each row while I would like to add 10 images to one row.

```
Table tmpTable = new Table();
tmpTable.add(img1);
tmpTable.add(img2);
...
tmpTable.add(img10);

masterTable.add(tmpTable).colspan(3);
```

What is the best way to do it? Is it possible to do it using another table (does not work for me)?

Comment: What specifically doesn't work with the code you provided?

Comment: I got some progress - when I remove 'pad' from tmpTable.add(img1) it does show up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about what you want to achieve here, but to add multiple Actors inside one cell you have multiple choices. If you want the images on top of one another exactly, then you can use `Stack`.

```java
Stack overlay = new Stack();
overlay.addActor(img1);
overlay.addActor(img2);
...
overlay.addActor(img10);

masterTable.add(overlay);
```

Please note, that adding the images to the stack will overwrite any positioning of the images, so the following line will have no effect:

```java
img1.setPosition(4,6);
img2.setSize(64,64);
(...etc)
```

If you'd like to position the images relative to the container, then you can use the raw `WidgetGroup` Container exactly like with `Stack`:

```java
WidgetGroup overlay = new WidgetGroup();
overlay.addActor(img1);
overlay.addActor(img2);
...
overlay.addActor(img10);

masterTable.add(overlay);
```

The only difference is that positioning will not be overwritten, so it has to taken care of (possible to set) manually.